# How to have onclick for options in react-dropdown component

Tags: reactjs, onclick, dropdown

I am new to ReactJS. I am creating a dropdown menu using react-dropdown component. Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown

Is there a way I can assign an onClick() event listener to the options that I send to the dropdown??

Comment: You already have a hook for that, right? The `onChange` prop function will be fired when they click on an option. It looks like you can't hook directly into the rendering of the options so you won't be able to directly apply an `onClick` to the option elements, but with the `onChange` prop you should be able to do whatever you need for when they click something

Comment: Yeah..I have a hook for that but can I know which of the options were selected from onChange??

Comment: I would assume it's passed as an argument to the `onChange` function. You can try it with an inline prop function, e.g. `onChange={(val) => console.log(val)}` does that print the selection?

Comment: It prints the object, but the original value of the dropdown is changed to current value.. I don't know why it's happening...Do you know any other components to create a simple dropdown without any default styling ??